# Where can I find tabulated data for reflectance per wavelength (for Cu, Ag, Fe etc)?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, spectroscopy

I'm looking for a tabulated data for reflectance per wavelength for various materials for the visible light range. I found only images so far. Are there any spreadsheets with the raw numbers?

Comment: [Three-dimensional digitization of highly reflective and transparent objects using multi-wavelength range sensing](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225100525_Three-dimensional_digitization_of_highly_reflective_and_transparent_objects_using_multi-wavelength_range_sensing)